# Функция mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Парни, подмогните. Что делаю не так? И как исправить? Буду очень благодарен!

```js
 $(".arrow").mouseover(
 function(){
  $(this).css('height', '40px');
 }
)
```

```css
#main{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.arrow{
 float: left;
 width: 3px; 
 background: white;
 cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.arrow_mini{
 height: 15px;

}
.arrow_big{
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="arrow arrow_big arrow_1"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_2"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_3"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_4"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_5"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_6"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_7"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_8"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_9"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow_big arrow_10"></div>
</div>
```

При наведении курсора - должна изменяться высота палочек...
Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего Ваш код в HTML документе подключен раньше чем jquery.
Подключите его **после** jquery и все будет работать как нужно.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #main {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .arrow {
      float: left;
      width: 3px;
      background: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #000;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .arrow_mini {
      height: 15px;
    }
    .arrow_big {
      height: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="arrow arrow_big arrow_1"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_2"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_3"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_4"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_5"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_6"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_7"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_8"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_mini arrow_9"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow_big arrow_10"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".arrow").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('height', '40px');
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: jQuery подключен первый, но спасибо! :)

Comment: Проверьте, я приложил код.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите код с изменением свойств css в функцию $(document).ready() и тогда, в Вашем случае, код можно будет описывать в любом месте

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".arrow").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css('height', '40px');
   });
});
```